# Recursively expand all child items of item in QTreeView

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qtreeview

I have a QTreeView and I want to expand all child items of a recently expanded item.

I tried using .expandAll(), but it expand all others items also.

I'm having a hard time to get the ModelIndex of the item that was lastly expanded, If i do have it I can recursively expand it's children.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To expand all nodes below the given one, I would do it recursively in the following way (C++):

```
void expandChildren(const QModelIndex &index, QTreeView *view)
{
    if (!index.isValid()) {
        return;
    }

    int childCount = index.model()->rowCount(index);
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        const QModelIndex &child = index.child(i, 0);
        // Recursively call the function for each child node.
        expandChildren(child, view);
    }

    if (!view->expanded(index)) {
        view->expand(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do I get the initial QModelIndex?

Comment: @f.rodrigues, what is the use model? How do you need to expand it? By clicking on a node?

Comment: The model is a QStandardItemModel(), and a node is expanded by clicking in it.

Comment: @f.rodrigues, ok, than handle the `QAbstractItemView::clicked()` signal of your tree view and you will get the initial index of the clicked node.

Comment: The clicked only gives emits its signal when I click on the name, not on the decorator '>' beside it.

Comment: @f.rodrigues, what about `QTreeView::expanded()` signal instead? But be careful, because the `expandChildren()` function I proposed will cause the expanded signal emition too.

Comment: Oh yeah, the expanded worked, I was using it, but with a lambda and it was losing the index in the process.

Comment: Working fine, just a minor complain. The animation of the expanding is complety gone, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @f.rodrigues Getting animations working is probably worthy of another question on SO. I have an idea, but way to long to post in the comments of another answer.

Comment: Should it not be `view->isExpanded` (Qt 5.6) and do you really think calling it is more efficient than just calling `expand`?

Comment: @DaRich, `expand` is already optimised for the case that the tree item is expanded. So the check is not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Qt 5.13
[`QTreeView::expandRecursively`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#expandRecursively)
is available